# Worklight Direct Update stuck in download loop

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-console

I am using Worklight 6.0.0.1, my application uses wlInitOptions, connectOnStartup and checks if there is any update on the server.

The Direct Update feature is behaving weird, sometimes the application
gets updated properly and sometimes it keeps on downloading and
unpackaging the application over and over. So far I have not found any
solution to it, I have made sure that my Worklight Studio version is
same as Worklight Server version.

> This happens on both Production and Test servers, I have followed both
> options, i.e. only Uploading the WLAPP file and in another try I
> re-installed the WAR file, re uploaded the WLAPP file, but still the
> problem persists. My production has two servers, both separate, and connected to a load balancer with sticky sessions enabled. My test has ONE server, connected to load balancer.
>
> I am using DB2 as a local database for all 3 servers. Surprisingly Worklight Studio (Development) works perfectly fine.  The problem is for both Android and iOS.

Below are the steps I am following:

1. Import the project in my Worklight Studio (Desktop)
2. Build and Run on local machine
3. Deploy all the adapters
4. Build and Run on local machine
5. Verifying functionality
6. Change the authenticationConfig.xml to use Console authentication (I use the same file every time with same username password)
7. Change the worklight.properties to point to production server
8. Provide console.username and console.password
9. Build for Remote Server (provide the URL of production/test server)
   10.Upload the application on the worklight console
10. Try opening the application.
11. First time Direct Update works fine, if I follow the same steps , on the next update it starts going in download and unpackage loop.

Anyone else experiencing the same ? any workarounds/solutions?

Comment: Is this happening in the Development environment or production environment? Is there more than 1 database involved in your setup? clustering? If you create a new project and application, does it happen as well? what are the exact steps you are doing? Please Edit The Question with this information (not in comments).

Comment: Also, what OS does this happen on ? Android / iOS / both ?

Comment: Hi Srik, The problem is on both Android and iOS

Comment: What's the datestamp on your 6.0.0.1 version on your test/production systems? There have been a few ifixes available since 6.0.0.1 came out; the latest has a datestamp of 20130926. Since you mention the Developer Edition is working; can you check if your test/production systems have the latest ifix?

Comment: Hi Barbara, 

Thanks for the reply, I have made sure that the date stamp is same on all three servers i.e. 20130926-1933.

While researching I have also found a solution which states that it happens if the application is running. But this appears illogical, since we can not ask our users to close the application at a specific time.

Comment: @eshaa, is this question resolved based on the below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem regarding Direct Update in a clustered production environment was recently fixed, and looks like it may also be related to purported issue in this question.

If you are an IBM business partner or customer, I suggest that you will notify your IBM contact person about receiving the latest iFix for Worklight 6.0.0.1, or wait for Worklight 6.0.0.2, to be released some time February 2014.